# K8s & Docker - ideal image design for sensitive params on GCP

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, msmtp

I'm working on a Docker image that bundles Apache with PHP7 and uses [msmtp](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/) for Sendgrid integration. The reason I like msmtp is there is no separate running process so it bundles nicely without need for an SMTP container.

That said, the configuration for msmtp looks like this

```
account sendgrid
host smtp.sendgrid.net
port 587
auth on
user apikey
password YOUR_API_KEY
from FROM@YOURDOMAIN.TLD
```

Ideally, the file will be all there with the values for `YOUR_API_KEY` and `FROM@YOURDOMAIN.TLD` somehow passed to the container at runtime.

Now I'm considering options for how to go about writing my Dockerfile... Given that I intend to run the container inside a pod on Kubenetes on Google Cloud Platform might impact this decision.

I've found out about things such as build time args ([`ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg)), environment variables ([`ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env)) and the like, in [this great article](https://vsupalov.com/docker-env-vars/).

It looks like build args would be a poor choice here based on the warning from the docker docks

> Warning: It is not recommended to use build-time variables for passing
>   secrets like github keys, user credentials etc. Build-time variable
>   values are visible to any user of the image with the docker history
>   command.

Given all of this, what's the best approach to create an image that will allow the credentials to be passed at runtime? I also still need to figure out a way to pass those arguments into the file when the container starts... Or should I forget all of this and just [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) the msmtp config in it's entirety for each client? That sounds a bit disastrous!

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton ! I remembered reading this before, but memory was hazy and google-foo was failing me...

Comment: It looks like I can handle the later part via a [`ConfigMap`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/). Essentially template the msmtp file w/ a ConfigMap that references the credentials via mounted Secrets... Crazy stuff.